# Chemical representation - SNL to SMILES

Tags: python, rdkit, cheminformatics

I would like to know whether is it possible to convert SYBYL Line Notation (SNL) into Smiles with Python?

**Example for N-methyl-pyrrolidone:**

```
SNL = 'N[1](CH2CH2CH2C@1=O)CH3'
SMI = 'CN1CCCC1=O'
```

I haven't found any solution with RDKit :(

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some examples. Not a lot of people are going to know what you mean by SNL/Smiles. Or maybe it's just me :P

Comment: Oh, so sorry :)

Comment: Could this help? Sorry I don't know too much about the domain itself: http://cirpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I use this tool everyday … shame on me ! It seems to be fine ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RDKit it's in AllChem.

```
from rdkit.Chem import AllChem as Chem
Chem.MolToSmiles(Chem.MolFromSLN('N[1](CH2CH2CH2C@1=O)CH3'))
'CN1CCCC1=O'
```

Comment: Beautiful :D. Thanks a lot